# Вытащить значение title в label средствами jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть блоки кода, подобные того что ниже. С радиокнопки при клике нужно вытащить значение title внутреннего label(title="Серый") и вывести его в html. Суть в том, что есть товары с разными цветами и когда кликают на опцию цвета, нужно что бы еще прописью в нужном блоке писало, что за цвет.

```
<div class="radiobox-colors__list-item option-value-id-103" style="opacity: 1;">
<input type="radio" name="option[464]" value="1326" id="close-type-1326">
<label title="Серый" for="close-type-1326" class="label label--img-1326"> 
</label>
</div>
```

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете запустить проверить:

```js
$('.radiobox-colors__list-item input').change(function () {
  const myId = $(this).attr('id')
  const color = $(`label[for='${myId}']`).attr('title');
  
  $('.content').html(color)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radiobox-colors__list-item option-value-id-103" style="opacity: 1;">
  <input type="radio" name="option[464]" value="1326" id="close-type-1326">
  <label title="Серый" for="close-type-1326" class="label label--img-1326"></label>
</div>

<div class="radiobox-colors__list-item option-value-id-104" style="opacity: 1;">
  <input type="radio" name="option[464]" value="1326" id="close-type-1327">
  <label title="Красный" for="close-type-1327" class="label label--img-1326"></label>
</div>

<div class="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте примерно следующим образом:

```
$("input[type='radio']").on("click", function(){
   $id = $this.attr('id');                   //получаем текущий id
   $label = $("label[for='" + $id + "']");   //с помощью id получаем label
   $label.html($label.attr("title"));       
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
   var color = $(this).parent().find("label").prop("title");
   alert(color);
});
```